# Delete tableview row and core data

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview

I would like to delete a specific table row in a table view controller and the according files in the core data database (all attributes that belong to the specific table row).
For example I tried following code but it always hang up with following error "invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (5) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)."

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
            let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)! as UITableViewCell
            let row_name = currentCell.textLabel?.text
            
            let context = getcontext()
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Test")
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phone= %@", row_name!)
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    
    
            let request = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest )
        
    
         if editingStyle == .delete {
             TestItem.remove(at: indexPath.row)
             tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
             
    
             do {
                 try context.execute(request)
                 try context.save()
             } catch {
                 print ("There was an error")
             }
            }
 
               self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Comment: Never call `reloadRows` right after `insert/delete/moveRows`. The latter updates the UI animated. And why do you create the fetch request outside of the `.delete` check?

Comment: Are you also deleting the element in the model represented by the cell you are deleting? Cause from your code that is not so clear since you're performing a batch delete operation on multiple objects in the core data context.

Comment: @vadian I'm not so familiar with swift and still learning, thank you for your comments.

Comment: @valeCocoa I tried several codes snippets, maybe the batch delete is not the right process for my plan. Yes I would like to delete the selected row and all CoreData entries which belong to this category. e.g. row "test" was deleted, I'll also delete all entries in CoreDataDemo which contains "test". I guess I'm missing some root understandings for Coredata..

Comment: @JosWico have you checked if the batch delete effectively takes effect despite the crash? What and where are sorted the items represented by the tableview's cells? 
Can't you just get that value `row_name` from the model by using the indexPath parameter, rather then look up for the cell?
Plus as vadian already pointed out you'd better not reload the whole tableview via `reloadData` in these circumstances: just enclose the tableview modification between a call to `tableView.beginUpdates()` and one to `tableView.endUpdates()`.